# Print items in array with increasing times

Tags: javascript

I have an array and I want every element in this array printed on the screen. But the time to print to the screen will be multiplied by 2 every time.

Example: a printed: 1 sec, b printed: 2sec, c printed: 4 sec...

How can I do that? This is my code. Can you help?

```js
let exampleArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

const writeArray = (arr) => {
    let time = 1000;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        console.log(arr[i])     
    }
}

writeArray(exampleArray)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "time to press the screen"?

Comment: Needed some clearity, you want to print a then after 2 second then after 2 second c??? print each element at 2 sec gap?

Comment: @JustIn no, I want to multiply the amount of time it takes to print each item by 2. a is written = 1sec, b is written = 2sec, c is written = 4sec, d is written = 8sec ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

Edit:
It prints to console every 2^i seconds. Have in mind, that i starts at 0, so you may want to use `Math.pow(2,i+1)*1000` instead...

```js
let exampleArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

const writeArray = (arr) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(arr[i]);
        }, Math.pow(2,i)*1000);    
    }
}

writeArray(exampleArray)
```

Comment: yeah, I wanted to do that. Thank you!

Comment: I edited my answer, because i starts at 0. So it does not **exactly** what you asked for, but is one step behind.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let exampleArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

const writeArray = (arr) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(arr[i])
        }, (i+1)*1000);    
    }
}

writeArray(exampleArray)
```

Comment: This is how I understand it too. But I think the questioner wants it this way: print A, wait 1 sec, print B, wait 2 sec, print C, wait 4 sec, print D.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly yeah, I want it to be just like you said.